# HTML Fixed header - Align position th at the same level as td

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I've created a table with fixed header and scrolling. It works really well, but the table header alignment doesn't match the table data. I mean, the result should be

```
--------------------
Id Heading2 Heading3
--------------------
 1  value1   value2
 2  value1   value2
 3  value1   value2
```

But in my table the headers doesn't match the table data which mean the headers are not aligned properly. Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yE44/). I've tried `padding`. But it didn't work. So, please help how to align the headers to match corresponding column? JQuery and Javascript solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one:**

html:

```
<table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="id">Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">1</td>
            <td class="name">Raja</td>
            <td class="position">developer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">2</td>
            <td class="name">Rajesh</td>
            <td class="position">associate consultant</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">2</td>
            <td class="name">Rajesh</td>
            <td class="position">associate consultant</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">2</td>
            <td class="name">Rajesh</td>
            <td class="position">associate consultant</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">2</td>
            <td class="name">Rajesh</td>
            <td class="position">associate consultant</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
 thead tr th
{
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
}
tbody
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:red;
}
tbody tr td
{
    width:100px;
}
.id
{
    text-align:right;
}
.name, .position
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: No scrolling still.. but alignment ok

Comment: add overflow:auto; in your tbody.

Comment: You need to specify the width of the tbody td to align them with the header. In order to have a scroll, you need to make it absolute...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this css:**

```
 thead >tr,th
    {
       border:none;
       padding:5px 20px 5px 10px;
       text-align: center;
       background-color:#0B3B17; 
       font-size:12pt;
    }
    td
    {
      border:none;
      color:#61210B; 
      text-align: center;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }
    table
    {
     display: block ;
     height: 100px;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     width:400px;
     background-color: #ddd;
   }
```